# Dividing space inside fluid container in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have this fluid container and its divided like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3">
sidebar
</div>
<div class="col-7">
top slider
</div>
<div class="col-2">
big button
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The next section i want to have is having 4 divs occupy area just beneath `col-7 + col-2`

Basically i want something like this [image]

I have tried creating another row beneath the existing row and having a blank col-3 but the four columns i want do not fall in place. How can i have the four columns like below?

Comment: Could you perhaps just have 2 main columns `col-3` and `col-9` with everything on the right hand side of that diagram being a `card` inside the right hand column? The side bar being in the left column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best shot. But the `row` on the right side is a new `row` so it also has `12 column`.

```css
div {border: solid coral;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container">
  <section class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-3">
      Col-3
    </div>
    <section class="col">
      <section class="row row-cols-4">
        <div class="col-8">Col-8</div>
        <div class="col-4">Col-4</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: This is very very elegant. I wonder if there is a way to still get responsiveness from those smaller boxes.